# Tailwind CSS Analyser

Tags: visual-studio-code, tailwind-css, next.js13

I would like to know if someone knows if there is a tool that could give me insights about my tailwind (v3) css classes used in my project. It is a quite big project, and I would like to find very rare used classes in order to maybe combine them in some global class and tidy up my final css and make my project more maintanable in the long-run.

I have used windicss in the past, and there is a tool that does exactly that :
https://windicss.org/features/analyzer.html

There also was a tool for Tailwind v2 : https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-analysis but nothing for tailwindcss v3 ...

But for Tailwind v3 I cannot find anything.

I am using visual-studio-code and the project is built with Nextjs13.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[tailwindcss-analysis](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tailwindcss-analysis) has been updated to support tailwind v3.